# Add ".local" to all devices on LAN

Tags: networking, dns, bonjour, zeroconf

The Apple devices on my LAN can be reached by xxxx.local.  What feature or protocol provides this service?  Is this `bonjour`?

Can the domain-name service on my modem/router (Actiontec C1000A) be configured to manage the name's of the devices (e.g. printer) that don't have this feature?

** edit **

Hoping to have these devices broadcast a .local name:

- brother printer --> printer.local
- actiontec modem/router --> router.local
- ipad
- two android telephones

Answer (score 1):

It is a function of Bonjour. You can get Windows PCs to resolve .local names by either installing Itunes (ick) or by installing the [Bounjour Print Service](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL999). Most *nix devices can be persuaded to broadcast .local mDNS names using [Avahi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29). Though Avahi can be a right pain to get working.

You may be able to enable either Zero-Conf, mDNS, or DNS-SD in the printer settings which may allow them to populate as with .local addresses.